# C++, Seg Faults, and Memory Management

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I'm moving from Java to C++ and have really enjoyed it.  One thing I don't enjoy is not understanding memory at all because Java used to do that for me.

I've purchased a book :  Memory as a Programming Concept in C and C++ - Frantisek Franek

Are there some good sites for me to go and learn interactively about C/C++ and memory use (tutorials, forums, user groups)?

Comment: This thread has a lot of useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c

Comment: Wow. Going from Java to C++ and enjoying it. I'm impressed.

Comment: Well, you're putting emphasis on the right thing, since understanding resource management is (IMHO) absolutely critical to being a competent C++ developer.

Comment: @JesperE Indeed, I was amazed myself.

I should probably mention that I'm doing this for educational reasons and not for work.  

I think if my boss wanted me to suddenly write an app in C++ it would be much more frustrating than fun.

Comment: I think "fascinated" is the term you're looking for, not "enjoying". ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/cplusplus-programming-tutorials/memory-management/

http://www.cantrip.org/wave12.html

http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2003/05/08/cpp_mm-1.html

And in wikibook: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Memory_Management

This article will compare the Java memory management operators with the C++ equivalents: http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/memory_management.shtml

http://www.infosys.tuwien.ac.at/Staff/tom/Teaching/UniZH/CPP/slides/cpp_07.pdf

Hope these will help you!

Comment: Great list. May I add this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html

Answer (score 5):

Memory management is nearly automatic in C++ (with a few caveats).

Most of the time **don't** dynamically allocate memory.
Use local variables (and normal member variables) and they will construct and destruct automatically.

When you do need pointers use a smart pointer.
Start with using boost::shared_pointer<T> instead of pointers.
This will get you on the correct path and stop accidently deleting memory at the wrong time and 90% of your code will release correctly (unfortunately cycles will cause a problem (in terms of leaks only) and you will need to design accordingly (but we have other smart pointers to deal with cycles weak_ptr))

My fundamental rule is that a class never contain a RAW pointer. Always use some form of standard container or a smart pointer. Using these; destructor calls become automatic.

Once you have the feeling start reading about the other smart pointers and when to use them:

[Smart Pointers: Or who owns you baby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby)

Comment: +1, especially for "Most of the time don't dynamically allocate memory."

Comment: @Martin - out of genuine interest: isn't using `shared_ptr` everywhere a bit slow? Would you recommend it, say, for a simulation or a videogame?

Comment: What makes you think it is slow? But no I am not recomending it for everywhere. I am recomending it as a starting point for learning about smart pointers. Use the correct smart pointer to solve the problem at hand (but you have to start somwhere and smart pointers is a rather large topic to jump in). PS. I have no problems with smart pointers in simulators (correctness is king, optimize after you show it is bottleneck).