# delete dynamically allocated object from std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

Is this correct?:

```
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
enemies.push_back(new Enemy());

Enemy* enemy = enemies[0];
enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + 0);
delete enemy;
```

Comment: The usual: consider using a vector of shared pointers, or a `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: Here's the link to boost pointer containers, the one Space_C0wb0y is talking about: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#basic-usage

Comment: You `push_back(new Enemy)`?  Didn't you know that it's unfair to push your enemy on the back? :-D

Comment: @Pavel: Not just unfair, but unwise: *Keep your friends close, and your enemies closer*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works, yes, but it's not an ideal approach.

Firstly, adding 0 is just noise, you can remove that. But even better, just use `pop_front()`. Also, no need for the intermediate step, you can delete before removing.

But `std::vector` isn't good as popping from the front, especially if it's large (because the remaining elements need to be shifted to fill the void). If you don't need contiguous memory, use a `std::deque` instead. Or, if order doesn't matter, you can use something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
void unordered_pop_front(std::vector<T, A>& vec)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(vec.front(), vec.back()); // constant time

    vec.pop_back(); // constant time
}
```

It swaps the front element with the back element, then pops it off. Of course, order is not retained.

The other problem is with your approach to memory management. Anytime you have explicit clean up code, you've done something wrong. It should be [done automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/please-help-us-non-c-developers-understand-what-raii-is).

Use either [Boost's `ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html), or a `std::vector` of [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby). (Note: do not use `std::auto_ptr` in a container, it's broken in this regard.) For a quick smart pointer suggestion, use either `std::unique_ptr` (if your compiler supports C++0x), or `std::/boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
enemies.push_back(new Enemy());
```

This isn't exception-safe. If `push_back` fails to allocate enough memory to accommodate the new pointer, then the `Enemy` object is leaked.

Using a vector of smart pointers can solve this, but failing that you should reserve the space in the vector before pushing back:

```
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
enemies.reserve(1);    // or more generally, enemies.reserve(enemies.size()+1);
enemies.push_back(new Enemy());
```

Now we know that `push_back` can't fail to allocate memory, and if `reserve` fails then the exception is thrown before the `Enemy` is created.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly looks fine to me. You don't need the `+ 0` in the `enemies.erase` line, but aside from that, it's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine.  You can simplify it a little:

```
delete enemies[0];
enemies.clear();
```

For removing the element, you could also use:

```
enemies.pop_back();
```

or (very similar to yours):

```
enemies.erase(enemies.begin());
```

Comment: What calls ~Enemy()? Is it the vector.erase()/vector.clear() or is it the delete enemies[0]?

Comment: @Ryan: `delete` calls the destructor of the pointed-at object, then frees the memory.