# Move constructor involving const unique_ptr

Tags: c++, constants, move, unique-ptr, move-constructor

In the code below, I made p const because it will never point to any other int during Foo's lifetime.  This doesn't compile, as the unique_ptr's copy constructor is called, which is obviously deleted.  Are there any solutions besides making p non-const?  Thanks.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo 
{
public:
  //x is a large struct in reality
  Foo(const int* const x) : p(x) {};
  Foo(Foo&& foo) : p(std::move(foo.p)) {};
private:
  const unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you need a `const unique_ptr` for? Maybe you want a `shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: I don't "need" it, but I'd like to indicate that p will point to the same int during Foo's lifetime.

Comment: If `p` will never point to another `int` then why use a pointer and not a normal member?

Comment: In my actual code, "x" is a large pod struct.  I rather pass a pointer than copy/move it.

Comment: You can either make it const and not allow Foo to be moved, or make it non-const. That's it sorry.

Comment: How about a reference? It can never 'point' somewhere else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The semantics of your move constructor are contradictory.

You have declared a `const std::unique_ptr` which will (uniquely) own the value it is initialised with.
**But** you've declared a move constructor that should move that value into another object at construction.

So what do you think should happen to the `std::unique_ptr` in the 'temporary' being move constructed from?

If you want it to be `release()`ed you've violated its `const`ness.
If you want it to retain its value you've violated the constraint of `std::unique` which requires no more than one such object to own any given object.
**Checkmate.**

This problem reveals a subtle limitation of the C++ language. It requires `move` semantics to leave the copied to **and** from as valid objects.

There are several quite reasonable proposals for 'destructive move' which would in truth better reflect what most uses of `move` are doing - take a value to here from there 'invalidating' what was there.

Google them. I haven't made a literature survey so don't want to recommend one.

Your alternatives here are to remove `const` or cast it way.
I strongly recommend removing it. You can make sure the semantics of your class ensure the appropriate const-ness with no impact and no 'ugly suspect' `const_cast`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo 
{
public:
  Foo(const int x) : p(new int(x)) {};
  Foo(Foo&& foo) :
    p(std::move(foo.p)) {
        
    };
    
    int get(void)const{
        return *(this->p);
    }
    
private:
     std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};

Foo getMove(){
    return Foo(88);
}

int main(){

    Foo bar(getMove());    
    std::cout<<bar.get()<<std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How would I use `const_cast`? I tried `const_cast` but received a compilation error: invalid use of const_cast with type ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’, which is not a pointer, reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type

Comment: I don't condone it but the code you're looking for is `p(std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int>& >(foo.p)))` in the initializers for the move constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that's the one line of code I was looking for in this thread (I understood why it wasn't compiling from the start).

Comment: @AgrimPathak: Glad to help. I think. I think it is technically OK to violate constraints of an object in move semantics so long as it leaves a destructible object.

Answer (score 3):

To understand why your code does not compile, reflect how you have declared `Foo` class and how `move semantics` is generally implemented.

Declaring a `const unique_ptr<T> p`, you mean that `p` itself will be never modified, but you could still modify the pointed-to object because of `T` is not const.

But `move` works on an opposite assumption. This feature uses the idea that is allowed stealing resources from objects and leave them in a empty state (if an empty state make sense). If can be useful, think `move` as a sort of 'destructive' copy for the moved object.

Writing `std::move(foo.p)`, basically you steal the resource pointed by `foo.p` and leave it in a safe state, that means assign `foo.p` to `NULL`. But `foo.p` was declared as const, so the operation is not permitted.

Please consider that in your case you don't need to declare p as a `const unique_ptr<int>`. Simply declare it as `unique_ptr<int>` and make sure that member functions are declared as `const` and non-member functions take it as
`const unique_ptr<int> p&` parameter. In this way you are sure that `p` will never change along the object lifetime (except in case of move operation).

Answer (score 2):

It is because `unique_ptr` has only the move-constructor, which means the initialization argument to `p` cannot be const, while `p` is const. I think what you wanted was to declare

> unique_ptr p;

instead of

> const unique_ptr p;

```
class Foo {
  public:
    // x is a large struct in reality
    Foo(const int* const x) : p(x) {};
    Foo(Foo&& foo) : p(std::move(foo.p)) {};
  private:
    const unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Concept of using std::unique_ptr is representing a sole ownership of an object. What you're trying to achieve is having a Foo class own an object (which is expressed by std::unique_ptr) **and** making it movable (your move constructor) which makes a contradiction. I would stick with std::unique_ptr or make it shared using std::shared_ptr.

You might want to read this:
[Smart Pointers: Or who owns you baby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby)

Comment: How does it make a contradiction? It's a move, not a copy?

Comment: The contradiction is a sole ownership of the object and moving it - after instantiating an object of class Foo it owns a "p" - it can not be moved later  and cause another object own "p", since its owned by the previous object.

Comment: Ownership can move. Why not? If it is done explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent transfer of ownership, you can use a `const std::unique_ptr<T>`. This is not very useful.

If you want to prevent modifying the object it holds, you can use a `std::unique_ptr<const T>`.