# Storing a raw pointer returned from a method into a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

**Scenario:**
I am using a method from an old C++ library which returns a raw pointer to `SomeClass` where `SomeClass` is an exported class from a library header say `SomeClass.h`

Following is the signature of `LibraryMethod` that I am using:

```
SomeClass* LibraryMethod();
```

I don't have access to change the library. I am using only the binary & public header which is a typical scenario.

I dont want to use raw pointers in my part of the code. Hence, I have a [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to `SomeClass` in my part of the code using the library API.

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> some_class;
```

which I initialise like this to avoid storing a raw pointer to `SomeClass`

```
some_class = (std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>)LibraryMethod();
```

This basically works but I want to understand the details here

**Question:**
Is the above a correct technique ?
Am I causing a leak here ?
Are there any better techniques to handle such a scenario ?

Comment: You should not mix C++ code compiled by different versions of the compiler. Doing so can lead to hard to find anomalies.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a `shared_ptr<>` and not a `unique_ptr<>`?

Comment: @RustyX as Your point would be valid if had access to changing the library's internal code. But unfortunately not

Comment: @gurka I think `unique_ptr` is out of the question here? as `LibraryMethod` is returning a pointer for another guy to point to. so this implicitly bumps reference count. hence a `share_ptr` is obvious choice ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'the second owner?', do you own that or not, if you own you can use either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, if you do not you cannot use either.

Comment: @Slava corrected my comment above to explain my choice of `shared_ptr` in a better way

Comment: No, it does not explain better, I do not understand what 'for another guy to point to' means.

Comment: @Slava looks like you gotcha me on that. I reconsidering my choice of the smart pointer type here. please share your thoughts on this as well.

Comment: Your question leaves out the most important piece of information: Who cleans up the pointer? Can the possessor simply `delete ptr;`? Do they have to call a `FreePtr` function in the library? Does the library somehow magically manage the pointer from afar? We see the library provides the pointer, but who owns it? Handy reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby

Comment: @user4581301 you are correct. besides, if I own the raw pointer returned into a shared or a unique pointer, then exiting the app gives me a malloc error complaining `pointer being freed was not allocated`.

Comment: Careful making that call. If you have not taken @CoryKramer 's answer into account, `some_class = (std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>)LibraryMethod();` will likely blow up something along the lines of what you just reported. Do you have any library documentation you can consult to determine ownership and handling of the pointer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should actually call it as

```
auto some_class = std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>(LibraryMethod());
```

This assumes that `LibraryMethod` is allocating the pointer and giving ownership of the memory to you.

As currently written, you are trying to cast the raw pointer to a `std::shared_ptr` using a C-style cast (which can result in a [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)). Instead you want to [construct a `std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) using the returned raw pointer.

Comment: I see that there is distinct difference in the way you have used braces here. I had used it around `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` but you have used it around the method call that is `LibraryMethod()`. this looks a **better way** of giving the ownership of the pointer?

Comment: It does not just *look* different, these two versions actually *are* different. Your method is doing a C-style cast which will likely not function correctly. This method is constructing a `std::shared_ptr` using the raw pointer as an argument.

Comment: "*constructing a shared pointer*". Is this better than doing a reset like suggested in below answer? really good suggestions here. want compare them to understand the best approach

Comment: @CoryKramer In this case, it will function correctly (since the C-style cast falls back to a `static_cast` if that is possible, and it is in this case). It's of course still quite dangerous.

Comment: If you construct it immediately following the call that's just one step. If you initialize it to `nullptr` then later populate it with `reset` that's two steps.

Comment: @CoryKramer: There is no ``reinterpret_cast<T>(p)`` where ``p`` is a pointer and ``T`` is a class type (for details, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). There are of course other dangerous possibilities, e.g. ``reinterpret_cast<T &>(p)`` will "work" if ``p`` is an lvalue. It is equivalent to ``*reinterpret_cast<T *>(&p)`` which is usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

In your case the correct way should be to use the shared_ptr constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> sPtr(LibraryMethod());
```

**BUT** first you should be aware what the pointer returned by `LibraryMethod()` really means, most libraries returns raw pointer just to say " hei, you can access this object trough this pointer, but watch out, I'm still the one in charge to manage it, so... do not delete it! "

If you are sure that after that call you are in charge to manage it, then ok, you can use a shared_ptr with the peace of mind.

Answer (score 3):

The code works, but it's ugly and fragile. Why mix nice modern C++ (smart pointers) with something as archaic and dangerous as a C-style cast? You're much better off calling `reset`:

```
some_class.reset(LibraryMethod());
```

The above assumes (as your question seems to indicate) that you already have `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> some_class;` declared somewhere and want to reassign it. If you're creating `some_class` just before the call of `LibraryMethod`, it's much better to directly initialise it:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> some_class(LibraryMethod());
```

This is then equivalent to [CoryKramer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672428/1782465).

---

Note, however, that there's a big assumption hidden in all this code: that `LibraryMethod` returns a pointer to memory allocated dynamically via `new` and that its caller is responsible for eventually releasing that memory by calling `delete`.

Comment: to your point, if we take ownership of the pointer then we are implicitly doing the required rituals of calling delete as well?

Comment: @Programist That's what `std::shared_ptr` normally does when the last of them goes out of scope, unless you supply a deleter which does something else.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the above a correct technique ?

Yes, given that the `LibraryMethod` allocates the resource with `new`, and the library user is responsible for deleting it. Wrapping raw pointers with smart pointers is widely-used for legacy libraries.

> Am I causing a leak here ?

No, if you do it correctly. I agree with other answers, but you can also do:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> some_class(LibraryMethod());
```

> Are there any better techniques to handle such a scenario ?

One thing to carefully consider is the ownership of the resource allocated by `LibraryMethod`. Some argue that `shared_ptr` is evil in  the sense that it is just a nicer way of introducing a global with dependencies which are hard to track. See [this talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) or [this one @8:40](https://youtu.be/QGcVXgEVMJg?t=8m40s) by Sean Parent for example. You may consider using [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead if there is an entity in your code that consumes and owns the resource.

Also if `LibraryMethod` may throw exceptions you have to handle this case accordingly.